# Deleting elements in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a **vector of structures**.

The structure has two elements **X and Y**, whose values are illustrated below.

**Assume:**

**Index    0     1      2      3       4      5      6      7       8      9**

**Value    a,b   c,d    e,f    g,h     a,b    a,i    a,i    a,i     j,k    l,m**

**My question: **
I need to keep the **latest occurrence of an element (x,y)** and delete the rest in efficient time, and with possibly auxiliary space.

Say, I start from the beginning of the vector, I encounter the element (a,b), and I need to delete this element plus all other (a,x)s, x can be anything here, but not **b**, but keeping the most recent **(a,b).**

Here, I need to delete elements at indexes **0, 5,6,7** and keep the one at **4**.

Elements are inserted using **vector.push_back()**, and hence the latest element is the one that is inserted at the end. (Insertion mimics that of a queue)

**My progress:**

i) I tried having a stable sort, but considering that I might run into an **O(nlogn)** complexity, I am not interested in this approach.

ii) The design in such that I can only iterate from the beginning and I cannot reverse that and start from the end.

iii) To reduce the complexity, I did something like:

```
 - Iterate vector from start to end.

 - For every elements, keep the search area to a smaller one by searching from the end.

 - Then delete all elements between current positions of forward iterator and the reverse iterator. This does not take the above illustrated case into consideration and works only when the most recent element is towards the end, i.e.in the above case, all (a,i)s are before the last (a,b)
```

Comment: is your question about efficiency or simply how to delete from a vector?

Comment: I cannot find any questions in your ... question ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115279/most-efficient-way-of-erasing-deleting-multiple-stdvector-elements-while-retai

Comment: I think you should just copy the vector to the new one, keeping only elements that you want to keep. This is done in one for loop and I think you 're not likely going to do more efficient than that.

Comment: @AlexPetrenko: I tried using a bitset and marking elements in one interation, and then using the set bits to delete the element in the subsequent iteration. But, am looking for an efficient way (if exists).

Comment: what is the (rough) problem size?

Comment: Currently, few hundreds, but can scale.

Comment: An how many elements have to be removed?

Comment: That might range anywhere from 1 to n, but will try adding logic to restrict the upper limit to a few tens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of anything faster than the naive approach:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct S {
    char X;
    char Y;
};

bool operator==(const S& lhs, const S& rhs ) {
    return lhs.X == rhs.X && lhs.Y == rhs.Y;
}

int main(){
    std::vector < S > src = { { 'a', 'b' }, { 'c', 'd' }, { 'e', 'f' }, { 'g', 'h' }, { 'a', 'b' }, { 'a', 'i' }, { 'a', 'i' }, { 'a', 'i' }, { 'j', 'k' }, { 'l', 'm' } };

    auto srcIt = begin(src);
    while (srcIt != end(src)) {
        // find last identical element
        auto le = find(rbegin(src), rend(src), *srcIt).base() - 1;

        char x = srcIt->X; 
        // delete all elements with same X value after last element 
        src.erase(std::remove_if(le + 1, end(src), [=](const S& e){return x == e.X; }), end(src));
        // delete all elements with same X value up to last element
        src.erase(std::remove_if(srcIt, le, [=](const S& e){return x == e.X; }), le);

        srcIt++;
    }

    for (auto& e : src) {
        std::cout << e.X << "," << e.Y << " - ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I'm not sure, whether it is possible to transform this into a single pass algorithm, but even then, the number of values against which you would have to test would increase in each step, so this would result in a similar asymptotic complexity (a few less copies maybe) but with probably more complex code.

In principle, you could replace the `erase remove` with a `copy_if` between two buffers, but I don't see how that yould improve performance, unless you want to throw multiple threads at the problem. In that case, I would let each thread copy the selected elements into a separate buffer and then concatenate them at the end of each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Mike.

Comment: @thenoGk: No worries. If you find a better solution, please let me know.